# Загрузка изображения с телефона

Tags: android, изображения, gallery

Доброго времени суток. 
 Как мне по нажатию кнопки вызвать галерею смартфона, там выбрать изображение и использовать его в качестве фона кнопки и не только?

Кнопка до: 
[image: Кнопка до]

Кнопка после:
[image: Кнопка после]

**Решил:** 
Использование `Intent.ACTION_PICK` и `Uri` решило мою задачу

```
static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

 imageButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.add_image);

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
            }
        });
...
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent);

        switch (requestCode) {
            case GALLERY_REQUEST:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    try {
                        final Uri imageUri = imageReturnedIntent.getData();
                        final InputStream imageStream = getActivity().getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUri);
                        final Bitmap selectedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(imageStream);
                        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), selectedImage);
                        imageButton.setBackground(d);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        }


    }
```

Comment: А вы пробовали искать в гугле? что конкретно не получается? Здесь люди помогают решать проблемы, а не просто *напиши код за меня*.

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий и в качестве ответа требует написать целую программу и решения множества вопросов, а не решить конкретную проблему. Переоформите вопрос так, чтобы он содержал конкретную проблему, которую вы не можете решить (не могу по нажатию кнопки вызвать галерею или как получить выбранное в галерее изображение или как установить фон кнопки)

Answer (score 0):

В самом тупом варианте, который гуглится за 3 секунды:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();  
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);  
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

В более современных версиях есть другие Intent'ы, но для начала этого вам хватит.

Comment: Думаю автору нужна реализация `onActivityResult` а не просто переход в галерею ))